# Alternatives to using fstream

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I am trying to read multiple lines of binary strings from a text file using fstream in c++. It currently works as it should but the strings cannot be manipulated normally. I need to reverse the strings after i read them from the file which causes the null terminator to be in the wrong place and cause all sorts of errors. Is there any alternatives to 'fstream' to reading data to strings or is there any ways i can reverse strings read in from a file without messing with the null terminator.

Heres a snippet of my code:

```
void Baby::getStore(string fileName, string* store){
    fstream myFile;
    int i=0;
    myFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::in);
    string currentLine;
    if(myFile.is_open()){
        while(getline(myFile, currentLine)){
            store[i] = Baby::reverseString(currentLine);
            for(int j=31; j>=0; j--){
                store[j]
            }
            i++;
        }
        myFile.close();
    }else{
        cout << "File not found\n";
    }
}

//reverses the string it is given
string Baby::reverseString(string rev){
    string temp;
    for(int i=rev.size(); i>0; i--){
        temp += rev[i-1];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps reading up about the keywork `const` and using `std::vector` and `std::array`

Comment: Your problem isn't `fstream`. It's that your `reverseString` function is broken. That's not `fstream`'s fault. It's also unclear what the inner loop around `j` is supposed to do. Overall, your code seems generally broken.

Comment: You wrote a wrong algorithm which has really nothing to do with fstream!

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry the loop around j was when i was trying to do something i should have removed it. In what ways is it broken? The reverse string seems to successfully reverse strings that are passed in that arent read in from a file. The lines are also succesfully stored in 'store' before they are reversed. It complies, it just doesnt handle the strings as expected.

Answer (score 0):

An other way to reverse strings without messing with the null terminator is the [std::reverse()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/) function.Include the algorithm header file and replace this:

```
store[i] = Baby::reverseString(currentLine);
```

with this:

```
std::reverse(currentLine.begin(),currentLine.end());
store[i] = currentLine;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using this at first but i thought that was causing the problems so i wrote my own but ive fixed it now and it wasnt the reverse function that was giving me grief